# Custom event on fragment change in Reveal.js

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

What would be the right way to programmatically add fragments to a slide in [Reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/)? I have a JavaScript widget on a slide that can go through 5 states, and I would like to go through them with fragment transitions.

I tried to achieve something similar with *dummy fragments*, like in the representative example below. This is intended to change the `src` of an image on fragment change. The example has an issue, though. When approaching a slide by pressing *previous* a number of times, the slide should start at its last fragment state. In the example, however, the image src starts in state 1, and doesn't know how to go further back on additional *previous*-steps.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

```
<img src="img1.png" id="my-image">
<span class="fragment update-img-src" data-target="my-image" data-src="img2.svg"></span>

<script>
Reveal.addEventListener('fragmentshown', function(event) {
    if (event.fragment.classList.contains('update-img-src')) {
        // Find the target image by ID
        var target = document.getElementById(event.fragment.dataset.target);
        // Keep a stack of previously shown images, so we can always revert back on 'fragmenthidden'
        if (target.dataset.stack == null) {
            target.dataset.stack = JSON.stringify([target.getAttribute('src')]);
        }
        target.dataset.stack = JSON.stringify([event.fragment.dataset.src, ...JSON.parse(target.dataset.stack)]);
        // Update the image
        target.setAttribute('src', event.fragment.dataset.src);
    }
});
Reveal.addEventListener('fragmenthidden', function(event) {
    if (event.fragment.classList.contains('update-img-src')) {
        // Return to the previously shown image.
        // Remove the top from the history stack
        var target = document.getElementById(event.fragment.dataset.target);
        if (target.dataset.stack == null) {
            console.log('Trying to hide', event.fragment.dataset.src, 'but there is no stack.');
        } else {
            var [_, ...tail] = JSON.parse(target.dataset.stack);
            target.dataset.stack = JSON.stringify(tail);
            // Set the image source to the previous value
            target.setAttribute('src', tail[0]);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I suspect this is going to be tricky. I looked at the revealjs code, and it seems to only derive its state from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky solution that I put together. It allows you to register any number of fragments on a slide with a callback function.

```
function registerFakeFragments(slide, fragmentIndices, stateChangeHandler) {
    const identifier = `fake-${Math.round(1000000000*Math.random())}`;
    let i = 1;
    for (let fragmentIndex of fragmentIndices) {
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        span.dataset.target = identifier;
        span.classList.add('fragment');
        span.classList.add('fake-fragment');
        span.setAttribute('data-fragment-index', JSON.stringify(fragmentIndex));
        span.dataset.stateIndex = JSON.stringify(i);
        slide.appendChild(span);
        ++i;
    }
    let currentState = null; // last reported state
    const listener = () => {
        const currentSlide = Reveal.getCurrentSlide();
        if (currentSlide && currentSlide === slide) {
            // Find the latest visible state
            let state = 0;
            currentSlide.querySelectorAll(`.fake-fragment.visible[data-target=${identifier}]`).forEach(f => {
                const index = JSON.parse(f.dataset.stateIndex);
                if (index > state) {
                    state = index;
                }
            });
            // If the state changed, call the handler.
            if (state != currentState) {
                stateChangeHandler(state);
                currentState = state;
            }
        }
    };
    Reveal.addEventListener('fragmentshown', listener);
    Reveal.addEventListener('fragmenthidden', listener);
    Reveal.addEventListener('slidechanged', listener);
}
```